# how to implement cascading static dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody help me in implementing cascading static dropdownlist in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Please be a little more specific.

Take a look at this:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx